# What is Shared Token Cache Credential authentication method?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, authentication

By reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.sharedtokencachecredential?view=azure-dotnet) and searching on the web I didn't find any explanation of what this authentication method is about. I think it may have to do with tokens acquired when logging in an application such as Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah that class comment isn't super good. If you want to figure out what it does by checking the source code, it's here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/SharedTokenCacheCredential.cs. But it probably is something akin what it says. It uses a shared token cache that many Microsoft made apps use, like Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @juunas, I tested it in Visual Studio 2019 with an App Configuration resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview) and having my account as App Configuration Data Owner of the instance and I couldn't authenticate.

Comment: The [docs around Azure.Identity library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#credentials) very explicitly do NOT highlight this class... nor do they mention user credentials (visual studio / cli) is supported:
`This library currently supports:
* Service principal authentication
* Managed identity authentication
* User principal authentication`

It seems to work in basic cases, but i have struggles in [edge case](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11559)

Comment: Probably best to watch this [changelog for updates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/d9d93df6c75797a6027c125ab3ff61b2ac894102/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/CHANGELOG.md).   


Also see how well the OLD library `AzureServiceTokenProvider` [was documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support)  for VS authentication

Comment: The latest source code is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/Credentials/SharedTokenCacheCredential.cs